# Finding resolvent for clauses

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus

I have the following question and am not sure how to do it.

Find the resolvent for the clause $\lnot p(x) \lor p(f(a))$ with itself. How can I apply the resolution rule here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply resolution of the clause with itself, first of all you make a copy of the clause in which you rename the $x$ variable.

$$ (\neg p(x) \vee p(f(a))) \wedge (\neg p(y) \vee p(f(a))) \enspace. $$

You then need to unify $p(y)$ and $p(f(a))$.  The most general unifier in this case is obviously $\{y \leftarrow f(a)\}$.  This gives you

$$ (\neg p(x) \vee p(f(a))) \wedge (\neg p(f(a)) \vee p(f(a))) \enspace. $$

Resolution gives you the original clause back.

Comment: how come you dont rename f(a)?

Comment: I've made the (usual, reasonably safe) assumption that $a$ is a constant symbol and $x$ is a variable.  Hence, $f(a)$ is a ground term, and one only renames and unifies variables.  In any case, you'd rename $a$ if it were a variable--I doubt it--but not $f$, which certainly isn't a variable.

Comment: ok i see by resolution (not p(f(a)) or p(f(a))) is false which gives us back the original correct?

Comment: Resolving $(a \vee b) \wedge (\neg b \vee c)$ results in $(a \vee c)$.  In this case $a = \neg p(x)$ and $b=c=p(f(a))$.

Comment: gotcha, thanks!

Comment: wait, last question, why do you unify p(x) and p(f(a)) instead of the two copies of the original clause after renaming?

Comment: Unification is done on a pair of complementary literals from two clauses.  The two literals must have the same predicate symbol (not an issue in this example) and exactly one of them must be negated.  You could pick $\neg p(x)$ instead of $\neg p(y)$, but the result would be the same, except for the name of the variable in the resolvent, which is not relevant in this context.